# R Integer Key, Value map

Tags: r, dictionary, hashmap, key-value

How do you make a simple integer map in R from key to value.

I want to interact with it this way:

```
id_map[245]
>> 3
id_map[123]
>> 4
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`environment`s are the closest thing to a hashtable in R. Unfortunately, they only support `character` keys.

```
ht <- new.env()
assign(as.character(245), 3, ht)
get(as.character(245), ht)
```

`environment`s are hashed, and will be more efficient than using a vector. Unlike other R objects, `environment`s pass by reference when supplied as the argument of a function.

You can easily use this to implement something that feels natural.

```
new.hashtable <- function() {
    e <- new.env()
    list(set = function(key, value) assign(as.character(key), value, e),
         get = function(key) get(as.character(key), e),
         rm = function(key) rm(as.character(key), e))
}
ht <- new.hashtable()
ht$set(245, 3)
ht$get(245)
# [1] 3
```

Comment: There is an error for `rm`. `> ht$rm(245): Error in rm(as.character(key), e) :   ... must contain names or character strings Called from: rm(as.character(key), e)`

Answer (score 1):

You could use a numeric vector which has the disadvantage that it would take extra effort to make it dynamic.

```
> id_map <- numeric(500)
> id_map[c(245,123)] <- c(3,4)
> id_map[245]
[1] 3
> id_map[123]
[1] 4
```

Or you could use a list which is a dynamic data structure :

```
 > id_map <- list(500)
> id_map[c(245,123)] <- c(3,4)
> id_map[245]
[[1]]
[1] 3

> id_map[123]
[[1]]
[1] 4
```

Note that with the second alternative that the "[" function returns a list, but you could use `"[["` to return a single value from that list:

```
> id_map[[245]]
[1] 3
> id_map[[123]]
[1] 4
```

Comment: the list solution creates 243 null elements, so it's acting like a (dynamic) vector, not a hashmap.  I can't find any way to make a sparse data structure keyed by integers; the closest thing is to stringify the integer.  `l <- list(); list(toString(245)) <- 3`.  Note that you also can't put the expression in the list constructor: `list(toString(245)=3` gives a "unexpected '='" error.